# How to count Blanks in N'th column in a ListObject table

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count Empty cells (Blanks) in the fourth column only. I tried the following code.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
```

In my case, I have a table with only one row and 4'th column has non-empty cell. I get the wrong value with my code. The code above returns 3 Blanks instead of zero - 3 blanks could be total number of blanks in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the specifics behind this bug but it seems closely related to a behavior that used to show up when you tried to reference the visible cells below the header in an [AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) range when the filtered range showed no visible cells. In that case, it returned all non-visible rows. While not completely the same, this miscount seems closely related. To the best of my knowledge, that bug has been corrected in Office service packs.

Use the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) to call a worksheet's [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22) to achieve the correct result.

```
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Debug.Print Application.CountBlank(.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange)
    End With
```